# Strategy about cloning crypted (LUKS) systems

Tags: linux-mint, encryption, disk-encryption

For a while, I ve being discussing here how to manage to clone one encrypted system on others.
My plan is to build a Mint system, 
then to encrypt it,
then to clone it.

Here is my process for achieving it. What do you think about ?
- first I build my system (let s say, my prototype)
- then I create an "init" script, which make the custom for others virgin Mint system.
- then I get a HDD and install Mint with encryption (full system).
- I clone this lattest one on N disks, and for each disk, I process my init script.
Olé.

Comment: FYI, it's not clear if you'll do this or not, but if you did a raw disk clone (copying the same LUKS data & header to each new drive) they would all have the same master encryption key. Even adding or removing a passphrase with luksAddKey or luksRemoveKey doesn't changge the master key, anyone with a passphrase could decrypt any other drive. You'd have to do a luksFormat on each new drive to get a new master encryption key, but mounting each drive & copying only actual files might be a better idea.

Comment: @Xen2050 : I do plan to do a raw disk clone. I m aware of being the same key, but I dont care for now LuksFormat on each drive seems impossible for now, since I plan to make a quite industrial production. I plan, then, to update full disks with a fresh key & disk image.